# Is the uniques approvals functionality correct?

Tags: uniques

When an owner of an item makes a call to `approve_transfer` he allows an account to make transfers with that item.

But if the owner transfers the item to a third account after making a call to `approve_transfer`(where he could have given access to his other account), he can transfer the item back to his account that he gave approval to before.

Isn't this a problem, shouldn't we reset the delegate account to `None` after every transfer? Or maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not correct, as we saw in your [MR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12145).